# Connect Hyperledger Fabric Explorer to fabric network hosted on different instance

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to connect blockchain explorer(running locally) with hyperledger network(running on ec2 instance). I am facing some issues. These are the steps I followed:

1. Hyperledger network is running on ec2 instance. Checked the logs and also made sure ports are not blocked by firewall.
2. Set sync type to "host" in explorerconfig.json
3. The network is non-TLS. So, given "tlsEnable": false in config.json file. Also used grpc instead of grpcs. The url is like grpc://2.43.155.20:7051, where 2.43.155.20 is the ip of ec2 instance.
4. After building, when I run ./start.sh, I get following error:

> 2019-02-26T09:40:11.361Z - [31merror[39m: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed
>   to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://localhost:7050
>   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {
>   Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://localhost:7050
>       at checkState (blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:720:16)
>   connectFailed: true } Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
>   Closed out connections

Can anyone let me know what could be causing this issue?

**Note: I installed explorer and fabric network on the same instance and connected them. It worked. Now, when I try to connect to a different instance where my network is hosted, it doesn't work.

**edit**

Location of config.json: blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json.

Content:

`{
  "network-configs": {
    "network-1": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "clients": {
        "client-1": {
          "tlsEnable": false,
          "organization": "Org1MSP",
          "channel": "mychannel",
          "credentialStore": {
            "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/credential",
            "cryptoStore": {
              "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/crypto"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
          "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
          },
          "connection": {
            "timeout": {
              "peer": {
                "endorser": "6000",
                "eventHub": "6000",
                "eventReg": "6000"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "organizations": {
        "Org1MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org1MSP",
          "fullpath": false,
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "$PATH/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
          },
          "signedCert": {
            "path": "$PATH/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
          }
        },
        "OrdererMSP": {
          "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "$PATH/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        }
      },
      "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
          "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "$PATH/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "url": "grpc://2.43.155.20::7051",
          "eventUrl": "grpc://2.43.155.20::7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
          }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
          "url": "grpc://2.43.155.20::8051"
        }
      },
      "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
          "url": "grpc://2.43.155.20::7050"
        }
      }
    },
    "network-2": {}
  },
  "configtxgenToolPath": "$SOME_PATH/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools",
  "license": "Apache-2.0"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Explorer is trying to connect to the orderer node, but he is using the wrong host. Did you checked the orderer node host in the config.json ?

> grpc://2.43.155.20:7050

Comment: Yes, orderer node host url is grpc://2.43.155.20:7050 in config.json. Still it is taking grpc://localhost:7050.

Comment: Can you post the config.json (without admin credentials) and make sure its in the right path?. `$(ANYROUTE)/blockchain-explorer/blob/master/app/platform/fabric/config.json`

Comment: Okey, all's good in your config.json file, i think the problem is in postgreSQL, you have old data of your old hyperledger fabric environment. Use the scripts inside this directory:
`/blockchain-explorer/blob/master/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db` to replace you old data for the new data

Comment: I dropped the database, and ran /blockchain-explorer/blob/master/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db/createdb.sh script. Checked in postgres table, all the tables were empty. ./start.sh basically populates these tables and it fails. So there were no records.

Comment: HI @Lancer did you find the solution ? I am facing the same issue with orderer